# Django Template Render Included Variable

Tags: django, django-templates

My question is basically on rendering variables. For example, let's say I have an object block, where block.text='{{ "hello"|trans }}'

I want to include this into my base template. The following will obviously not work for what I intend.

```
{% include block.text %}
```

How might I render this into my template?

Comment: is what you want render the content of a variable that you translated inside python code? include tag is for including a template, not a variable, i don't get what you want to achieve

Comment: "is what you want render the content of a variable" YES. "include tag is for including a template, not a variable", You are correct, but I am trying to achieve functionality like that. To achieve it does not require the include tag. Perhaps I need to create a custom tag?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem a good idea generate dynamic templates from view side to render into a template.

But remember do you have other elegant approach like:

- [Inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) Is type of template tag that displays some data by rendering another template.
- [Include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) "Loads a template and renders it with the current context."

Also, take in mind, that you can use IF statement into a template to include or not include some template and, also, you can pass additional context to the included template using keyword arguments (ex: `{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}` ).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your tips. In my actual setup, I'm considering storing templates in the database rather than in files. That is why I'm searching this functionality.

Comment: You can take into account this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbtemplates